# Spring security without redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring Security implementation that is stateless and uses token-based authentication. Most of my logic lives inside of a class that extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. My problem is that after authentication is successful, AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter does a 302 redirect, which I don't want. I just want the original request to complete. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to make the "login" rest method exposed by spring security to return "200 OK" rather than "302 Redirect" by overriding the success and failure handler.
The below code shows how to achieve the same.

```
        //configure http by using the successHandler 
        //and failure handler methods
        http.
            formLogin()
                .loginPage("/authentication/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authentication/processLogin")
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                .failureHandler(failureHandler())
            .and()
            ......



    private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
            public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication Failed. Wrong username or password or both");
            }
        };
    }


    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*180);
                response.getWriter().println("LoginSuccessful");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I also had to add `.httpBasic(httpBasic -> httpBasic.authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint()))` otherwise Spring was subsequently  overriding the 401 with a redirect

Answer (score 0):

I came up to this issue when writing a custom authentication mechanism, from what i understand, when  writing a custom filter by extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, and using this filter on the security config, i needed to override the `successfulAuthentication` method on my filter(and just writing `chain.dofilter(req,resp)`), because default behaviour always seemed to use redirection. Now i don't know this is because of some security issue, but for my needs, i disabled the redirection this way, and wanted to share. Have a nice day!